# Phrase to give a non-detailed answer/explanation

Tags: word-usage, expressions

What expression could I use when giving non-detailed answers/explanations about how something works? Let's say I want to explain how a printer works without getting into too much detail, Would it be OK to say:

- "At a very superficial level, a printer ...."
- "At a very high level, a printer ..."

I feel like there are more appropriate expressions to begin such type of sentence. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Essentially? E.g “a printer essentially works like a paintbrush” Basically definitely works. Fundamentally could too. Oo I’ll make a sentence out of all of them: Essentially, the words you are looking for are fundamentally the synonyms of a wide variety of basically related words.

Comment: @CalendarJ What about the expressions I mentioned? Are they correct? What other word can i use after "At a very ..." to communicate that the answer is not very accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In simplest terms," would probably work for that purpose. Or "Without getting too technical/specific/detailed..." Or, if you want just one word, "Basically," would suffice.

"Basically, a printer works like this..."

Answer (score 3):

**Layman's Terms**

Definition: layman's terms (=in words that someone who is not an expert can understand)

*"In layman's terms, a printer ...."*

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

To put it simply,
To put it plainly,
In short,