# Can "More" be used with "simply put"?

Tags: conjunctions

Can "**more**" be used with "**simply put**"?

I would like to write: "**More simply put,** ..." giving a simpler explanation of the idea in context.

I couldn't find useful answers for this question on the internet. Any other synonyms of this phrase are welcome too.

Note: This is for a scientific paper.

Comment: or _put more simply_...

Comment: 'Putting it more simply' and 'To put it more simply' are perhaps the most idiomatic variants.

Comment: Does this answer your second question? [Phrase to give a non-detailed answer/explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451959/phrase-to-give-a-non-detailed-answer-explanation) 'In layman's terms' / 'Dumbing down'. The snag is it soon becomes 'Let me now give the Idiot's Guide.' A hedged 'Perhaps I could explain this more simply by ...' is less accusatory. Then there's the densely  hedged  'Perhaps I could explain this more cleary by ...' with the implication that you didn't make a good job of it first time round.

Comment: Yes. It is common enough: (1) A complicated explanation is given and the audience do not understand -> (2) "Simply put ...{plus either a simpler explanation or a summary}" and some of the audience still do not understand -> (3) "More simply put,..." An *even simpler* explanation/summary is given. (Stage 2 may be omitted.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

[Judging by nGrams its not particularly famous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simply%20put%2C%20more%20simply%20put&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csimply%20put%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20simply%20put%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csimply%20put%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20simply%20put%3B%2Cc0) compared to the basic phrase "simply put"

While there might not be much grammatically wrong in the phrase, it is unnecessary since "simply put" is more idiomatic and conveys the same meaning unless you're drawing a comparison to a statement that has already been simplified once before in the text.

Comment: If you only use phrases that score highly in Ngrams, you will be speaking in clichés.

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps. But I don't remember asking him to do that. I merely told him which version is more idiomatic and in which instance the version he used might be more meaningful.